# Can I prevent the browser from trying to parse html retrieved using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have some code that attempts to validate that a url is awake. It is intended just to check if a web service is awake. I am using jsonp so that I can make the cross domain script work, which it does, but I have also noticed another side effect. Whenever jquery retrieves the data from the url I provide, I get an error in my browser. It seems like the browser is trying to read the html that has been retrieved.

```
url += '?callback=?'; //the same as setting datatype to jsonp
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", dataType: 'json', url: url,
        timeout: 6000
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        callback(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    }).fail(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        callback(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    });
```

I have tried passing converters, changing the data types, the content types, and everything else. Nothing works.

In my console I will see an error like (assuming I were to request data from aol.com)

[image: Error from get request]

Is there any reason why  the html isn't just returned as a string that gets handled by jquery? It does hit the "Done" function, so  jquery isn't seeing any sort of errors, but the browser still thinks there is one.

Thanks

Comment: is it jsonp? cross origin? Then it expects jsonp and throws error on html. You could try dataType 'jsonp text xml', not sure if this works, but give it a try.

Comment: Gave it a shot, same issue. Adding ?callback=? to the url is similar to saying dataType: jsonp (which I have tried), so I am using jsonp. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Easiest way to solve is a server side proxy, using curl for example grep the response and forward this to your JavaScript

Comment: `url+= url.indexOf("?") >= 0 ? '&callbacks?' : '?callbacks?';`

Comment: Nobody has had this issue before? That's very surprising.